# SQL Error: ERROR: not all tokens processed

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

Am getting below error in Postgres while executing insert and delete queries. I have around 50 inserts and 50 delete statements. When executed an getting the error as,

**SQL Error: ERROR: not all tokens processed**

The error is not consistent all the time,
For example,
My 20th delete statement is getting failed
Next time when the same queries are executed, 25th delete statement is getting failed

And when those statements are executed alone, there is no failure.

Not sure if it is a database load issue or infrastructure related issue.
Any suggestion would be helpful

Below is the query,

```
 WITH del_table_1 AS 
(
delete from table_1 where to_date('01-'||col1,'DD-mm-YYYY') < current_date-1
RETURNING *
)  
update control_table set deleted_count = cnt, status = 'Completed', 
update_user_id = 'User', update_datetime = current_date from
(select 'Table1' as table_name,  count(*) as cnt from del_table_1) aa
where 
control_table.table_name = aa.table_name
and control_table.table_name = 'Table1' 
and control_table.status = 'Pending';
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, included the query as well

Comment: My bad forgot to provide the condition in the question. Its failing along with the condition